# How to render a View using AJAX, JQuery with Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

How to render a View using AJAX, JQuery with Spring MVC.

What is the best design model I should use for render a View using AJAX, JQuery with Spring MVC in a Web Project.

In the past I did Spring/Java programming and I made each screen a JSP file. So everytime I need it to display a new screen I did a call to the server and loaded a new JSP.

Now with Ajax and JQuery

I can have the JSP page and then use JQuery to change the screen with DIVs to make it look like new pages without going to the server, The only issue is how to I display this?? any easy way

I am thinking that using Ajax and JQuery will make me cut down on the number of JSP pages I have to have but I dont want to have one file with alot of javascript in it and its very hard to render the screens with javascript.

I am thinking it maybe to have the diffent parts of the screen load using ajax has need it but having them on the screen has diffent JSPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to incorporate ajax calls into your web application, you have a couple fundamental choices to make. You're going to make an ajax request, and get back a response. What response will that format be in?

There are two very common options:

1. JSON, that you then use to populate elements of your page. You don't need a JSP at all to do this, your server side spring controller just needs to stream back the data your page needs, in JSON format. I recommend the [GSON serializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), but there are several others as well.
2. HTML fragment, which will then be populated in a div (or similar). Instead of returning a full page here, you're just returning part of a page, which your javascript will then display. This option is better if you want the view rendering/logic to be handled on the server side.

The second approach is kind of what you describe in your question. It's a valid approach in the sense that people do it, but I generally prefer having my asynchronous calls use JSON, and have the view logic contained on the source page, and hidden from view if necessary.

To answer your question about hiding and displaying DIV elements, the answer is to use jQuery's [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

Answer (score 0):

Should take a look into backbone.js

It's a javascript framework which relies on a RESTful service to provide persistence and fetching.

The framework itself is very well designed and separates out the view logic from the model layer, etc.

If you choose the jsp solution of loading information based off of different views I might suggest a different approach.  Instead of your controllers returning jsp views, return JSON instead and have the ajax render the json.  Rendering this information can be done very cleanly through a templating system such as handlebars, and leads to less code clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any JSP/JSTL and keep your pages in clean HTML and CSS only. Use a wireframe like 360 or whatever to create your page templates. You use this wireframe to place your view-lets where required.

Then assign a `<div id="viewlet1"></div>` for each of those viewlets.

Load a Java script file, which contains a binding for each of the viewletids to a rest function. Example:

```
var viewlets=[ ["#custmeraddress","/customer/address"],["..","...."],...]
```

In the DocumentReady, bind the Rest response to the respective locations, for example:

```
$(viewlets[0]).load(viewlets[1]);
```

That fetches html from each rest function to its corresponding location.

Each of the rest functions must produce only XML. They must not produce any HTML. Each rest function, before it returns the content, should transform the XML into HTML using XSL.

Keep a set of master XSL files and function specific includes to transform any rest generated XML to HTML.

All rest functions should delegate the data access to a master DAO. the master DAO itself should have no idea about the producers and consumers, it should just mediate. Keep all SQL used by the master DAO in a bean specification or a static XML file. Every query must be in this Query Library file, so that the query results can be cached by a cache manager.

Depending on the rest function, the master DAO finds the required XML, applies the params from the request object, creates an XML fragment and return to the rest function.

The master DAO can also be a consumer of a cache-manager. Cache manager intercepts all reads and writes, analyzes the SQL and validates/invalidates the cache image of any query in the Query Library.